# Where can I get a CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check ) code?

Tags: c, matlab, crc

I am looking for a package, or easy implementation of CRC 16-bit code by MATLAB

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to translate C code to MatLab.

Comment: There is no need to translate, check the documentation how to compile and use c-functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about file exchange?
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20350-16-bit-itu-t-crc

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH ... BUT THIS SITE DOESN't WORK IN MY COUNTRY IF YOU COULD UPLOAD IT ANYWHERE ELSE I WOULD BE THANKFULL

Comment: @user1102780, all due respect, I believe that is not part of the services that Stack Overflow users should be doing for you.

Comment: @user1102780: Start by turning your caps lock key off... People might be much more willing to help you if you weren't screaming at them.

Comment: @Cody Gray & @ Andrey i am sorry i didn't know that when you turn caps lock on that means that you scream at them .. i am really sorry .. also thanks Andrey the site has just worked properly ..